# Read coordinates from many files and calculate polygon areas

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded, numpy, computational-geometry

My goal with this snippet is to create an array of coordinates which in turn is a tuple of 68 elements, area and modified area array for all 10k elements and assign it to the `df` column.

- Running the complete code results in 5.3, 4.8, 4.6, 4.5 seconds.

```py
#%%

arrayc = [] #array for array of coordinates
areaAr = [] #area type 1
modifiedarea = [] #area type 2
ts = time.time()

for i in range(10708): #number of files
        f = open(df["filepath"][i], "r") #df has column of filepaths 
        x,y = [], []
        for l in f:
            row = l.split()
            x.append(int(float(row[0]))) #68 pairs are of kind 3.82382323e+02 4.563524234e+02.
            y.append(int(float(row[1]))) #I am taking int rounded off to three digits.
        arrayc.append((x,y))
        f.close()
        #x= arrayc[i][0]
        #y = arrayc[i][1]
        areaAr.append(PolyArea(x[36:41],y[36:41]))
        distance = max(np.abs(x[36]-x[39]),np.abs(x[42]-x[45]))
        modifiedarea.append((PolyArea(x[36:41],y[36:41]))/distance)        

te = time.time()
print(-ts+te)
def PolyArea(x,y):
        return 0.5*np.abs(np.dot(x,np.roll(y,1))-np.dot(y,np.roll(x,1)))
```

How can I minimise the execution time ?

Updates:

- File generator code:

```py
import numpy as np 
filepath = []
root = '~/Desktop/test/'
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(68):
        numx = ( np.random.randint(100,200))
        numy = np.random.randint(100,200)
        f = open(root + str(i) + ".txt","a")
        f.write(str(numx) + " " + str(numy) + "\n")
```

- The numbers 36 41 etc are the coordinates of the polygon of interest on the image. It is fixed that the polygon will always be marked by these coordinates.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. Your timings include I/O, which is notoriously difficult to do in an unbiased way. Opening (and, to a lesser extent, reading & closing) a legion of files is going to take its time, sweet or not. Did you repeat the measurement for the first case immediately following one of the others?

Comment: @greybeard I am currently running the different tests on terminal, instead of integrated jupyter. Can you clarify which order should I run them in? I can do the same in Jupyter if it matters. But the order first. :)

Comment: The order *should* be almost immaterial. Running from an empty block&file cache as opposed to a primed one *may* make all of a difference: in an automated way, do each of the approaches in turn, about seven "turns". Put the first runs aside and have a look on the variance of the remaining readings.

Comment: @greybeard the runtimes are more consistent now. My laptop was under load when I ran the 21 seconds etc tests. A lot of apps were running, jupyter GUI was also less responsive and had a lag. Had to put laptop to sleep, freed up some space and restarted VScode and now the readings are,: around 1 second for area calculations, around 2 -3 for landmarks and total being 4-5, in both Terminal and Jupyter. For minute details, see if anything can be changed in the code itself.

Comment: Please see [What (not) to do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and roll back any changes to the code presented.

Comment: "The low-hanging fruits" are not handling a lot of files and not doing things over (like the duplicated call to `PolyArea()` [Georgy spotted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/225450/93149), too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't run your code, so I can't say how much faster the following will be.

My suggestion is to use NumPy's [`loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) function to get the array of the necessary coordinates. With this function, you can specify `skiprows` and `max_rows` parameters to get the necessary rows, 36-45. This should be more efficient than reading all the file in memory.

Here:

> ```
> areaAr.append(PolyArea(x[36:41],y[36:41])) 
> distance = max(np.abs(x[36]-x[39]),np.abs(x[42]-x[45]))
> modifiedarea.append((PolyArea(x[36:41],y[36:41]))/distance)
> ```

you calculate `PolyArea` two times, but it is enough to calculate it only once and then reuse the result.

The final code could lool like this:

```
for filepath in df['filepath'].iloc[:10708]:
    values = np.loadtxt(filepath, 
                        skiprows=35,
                        max_rows=10)
    x = values[:, 0]
    y = values[:, 1]
    area = PolyArea(x[:5], y[:5])
    areaAr.append(area)
    distance = max(np.abs(x[0] - x[3]), np.abs(x[6] - x[9]))
    modifiedarea.append(area / distance)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the same PolyArea function, Priority order goes like this:

Order of milliseconds.

```py
def PolyArea(urll):
        values = np.loadtxt(urll, skiprows=35,  max_rows=10)
        x = values[:,0]
        y = values[:,1]
        x = x[:5]
        y = y[:5] 
        return 0.5*np.abs(np.dot(x,np.roll(y,1))-np.dot(y,np.roll(x,1)))

df["areaAr"] =   PolyArea(df['filepath'].all())
```

The above method is fastest that I tried. Below is another with order of single digit seconds.

```
def PolyArea(urll):
        values = np.loadtxt(urll, skiprows=35,  max_rows=10)
        x = values[:,0]
        y = values[:,1]
        x = x[:5]
        y = y[:5] 
        return 0.5*np.abs(np.dot(x,np.roll(y,1))-np.dot(y,np.roll(x,1)))

df["areaAr"] =  df.apply(lambda row: PolyArea(row['filepath']), axis=1)
```

Below is another moderate method. Still better than crude iteration which goes double digit.

```
def PolyArea(urll):
        values = np.loadtxt(urll, skiprows=35,  max_rows=10)
        x = values[:,0]
        y = values[:,1]
        x = x[:5]
        y = y[:5] 
        return 0.5*np.abs(np.dot(x,np.roll(y,1))-np.dot(y,np.roll(x,1)))
for index,row in df.iterrows():
        areaAr.append(PolyArea(row["filepath"]))
```

Source, Medium blog: https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

Comment: The first code looks strange. [`pd.Series.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) returns `True` or `False`, so I'm not sure how you managed to run it without getting an error. The difference in time between the second and the third code, AFAIK, should be minimal as `apply` also runs a loop under the hood.

Comment: @Georgy yes, first one is troubling. I didn't verify after I used the `.all`. I meant to do something like `df["areaAr"] =   PolyArea(df['landmarkpath'])` but got `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`. Ik it's offtopic, but I would appreciate directions/edits. I should have taken care of series in `PolyArea` function. Since all other use loops, only this is different.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have experience of improving performance further than what you have right now. I don't think you can squeeze more out of NumPy or pandas here. For some directions, take a look at [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) and [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/), or try out [PyPy](https://pypy.org/). I've never tested them myself though.

Comment: Regrettably, I'm out of my depth, here.